# How to get array of pixels using openCv in Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am using tegra developer pack and I wanted to use openCv to get a camera image as an array of RGB pixels. I have tried:

```
VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture();
    Mat mat = new Mat();
vc.retrieve(mat);
```

But the only thing I get is error.

Comment: Post the error please ;)

Comment: check [my question here][1] and the answers maybe it will help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631029/android-mat-get-area-of-15x15-pixels