# Android Mat.get() area of 15x15 pixels

Tags: java, android, opencv

help is requested.
Im able to get pixel information of a specific point in camera preview using openCV

```
    @Override
public void onPreviewFrame(Mat image) {
    if (image == null || image.empty() == true) return;

    int w = image.cols(); //640 columns
    int h = image.rows(); //480 rows
    double [] p = image.get(h/2, w/2); //dividing them getting 1 point = 1 pixel
    if (p == null || p.length < 3) return;
    overlay_view.setRGB((int)p[2], (int)p[1], (int)p[0]);
}
```

but how i would get the array from 15x15 pixels area that will start at h/2 and w/2 points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(Mat image) {
    if (image == null || image.empty() == true) return;

    int w = image.cols(); //640 columns
    int h = image.rows(); //480 rows

    double[][][] array15x15 = new double[15][15][3];

    for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 15; col++) {
            double[] p = image.get(w/2 + row, h/2 + col);
            if (p == null || p.length < 3) return;
            else {
                array15x15[row][col] = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, this solution works for me. It can be that other answer is good, but i wasnt able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROI functionality of OpenCV:

```
Mat roi = new Mat(image, new Rect(x, y, width, height));
```

The Mat roi will point to the same data as the original image, so consider that when changing the data.

Comment: To get a ROI in java it is better something like: image.submat(new Rect(x, y, width, height));